# How can you mark a field as persisted but not serialized?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, serialization

I have an entity that must implement Serializable. It has a field which should be excluded from serialization, which can be done with the `transient` keyword:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private transient MyNonSerializable myField;

    // ...
}
```

However, JPA/Hibernate now also views the field as transient, which is not what I want. How can I mark the field as persisted but not serialized?

Comment: This has a certain unclean smell to it. If a single entity is persisted in two different ways, you might actually need two separate classes to represent it. **Especially** if the set of information persisted between those two ways is not identical.

Comment: In my real-world problem, `MyUserDetails` needs to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`, which in turn implements `Serializable`. But it also has a reference to `MyUser`, which in turn has a reference to `MyUserDetails` (via a bidirectional `@OneToOne` mapping). For persistence, the circle is fine, but for serialization, I have to break it. So, Spring kind of forces this upon me.

Comment: you could write your own writeObject and readObject: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/serialization/custom-serialization-readobject-writeobject/

Comment: That's the answer, then. Thanks! Apparantly, I did not use the right keywords in my web search. (I got distracted by all the hits for the @Transient annotation.)